# When downloading the div as as pdf the dynamic image is not displaying in the pdf file in angular 6

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

> when i am using the below function i can able to display the image in pdf which is stored in the local computer. but when i am trying display the dynamic image the image is not showing in the pdf file.

I am in struggle. anyone can help me to solve this. thanks in advance

```
 downloadGraphPDF(){  
var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
  var imgWidth = 208;   
  var pageHeight = 295;    
  var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
  var heightLeft = imgHeight;  

  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg')  
  console.log(contentDataURL)
  let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
  var position = 0;  
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'JPG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
  pdf.save('document'.pdf'); // Generated PDF });}
```

Comment: Make sure "data" contains the correct image, make sure contentDataUrl contains the correct base64 jpg image, make sure you use addImage correctly and be sure that the lib doesn't throw an error. Then tell us the result for all these steps.

Comment: hi @Pierre. i have checked. the data contains the correct content of the div and especially the image as well.and contentDataUrl contains the base64 jpg format, and there is no error occurs when the addImage() get triggers.